# Admin Panel pagination link styles

Tags: plugins, admin, pagination, css

Whenever I write plugins that use Admin Panels, I include some form of pagination using the `paginate_links` method and I have always been able to style them in a nice way using the suggestions on [this blog post](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/07/01/how-to-design-and-style-your-wordpress-plugin-admin-panel/). Recently, however, I have been unable to find the secret sauce to make this work. I'm guessing it's the way the divs on my pages are set.

Does anyone have the proper style declarations for using real WordPress pagination links? (Look at that site for what I'm looking for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fantastic, once again researching my question has provided an answer. For those interested, surround your pagination links in `<div class="tablenav"><div class="tablenav-pages">LINKS</div></div>` to get better looking number links.

(moved to answers as suggested by SickHippie)